# Post datepicker value when changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap.datepicker to set a datepicker in one of my Asp.Net MVC 5 Views. I want to post the date whenever a new one is selected. My code looks as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group form-horizontal">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date,  new { @class = "form-control datepicker", data_provide="datepicker", data_date_format="dd/mm/yyyy"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
}
```

Hoever, I don't know how to force the `Post` method when I select a new date.

Comment: You need to use javascript/jquery to handle the `change` event of the datepicker and trigger a submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscribe to the datepicker's [changedate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event and post the form:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit(); // or this.form.submit();
});
```